# remove android layout marging

Tags: android, xml

My problem is the white space between the imageview and the screen, i want that imageview width to be the same as the sceen ,so is there a way to remove this margin (the white space) from xml file ?
this is the screenshot
http://s15.postimg.org/coxrf6b2z/Capture.png
i didn't find any solution...

and the xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/layout_back"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame"
>

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/fl"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame" >




    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image_header"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:src="@drawable/wlp" />


    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="68dp"
        android:background="@drawable/gradient"/>


    <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:text="@string/bienvenue"
            android:id="@+id/tvBienvenue"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="false"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:textColor="#ffffffff" />

    <Spinner
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/spinner"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />


 </RelativeLayout>

 <ListView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/listView"
        android:layout_below="@+id/fl"
        android:layout_above="@+id/l1"  />

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="false"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:gravity="bottom"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:id="@+id/l1"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">


    </LinearLayout>

 </LinearLayout>
```

thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0):

I think this is caused by your `android:scaleType="centerCrop` for your `ImageView` try setting it to `FIT_XY` and see what happens.

Comment: no nothing changed.... this layout represent a fragment for swipeview activity.. i think this may help you to anderstand

Comment: sorry it should be `android:scaleType="fitXY"`. But if that doesn't work I would set the background color to be pink or something and see if the it is actually margin or if it was padding. If the color appears, it would be padding, otherwise for some reason your `ImageView` is actually that size. Then I would set the color to its container and see what the heck is going on.

Answer (score 0):

There is no Margin or Padding in your layout and I copy pasted your code and see no margin. Make sure its not part of your picture.

The Center Crop will fill the image view as well. thats not your problem.

Comment: it is not a part of the image look at this picture http://s3.postimg.org/kk7hk0jjn/Capture.png it was captured after selecting the imageview